# parent child process in nodeJS

Tags: c, node.js, fork

How to Create NodeJS equivalent for the below simple C code?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (fork()) {
        printf("I'm parent %d", getpid());
        printf("From parent : %d", 1+1);    
    } else {
        printf("I'm child %d", getpid());
        printf("From child : %d", 10+20);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fixed your code and formatting.

Comment: thanks.I'll keep this in mind,while posting hereafter.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? You might have better luck if you can provide more information...

Comment: I'm planning to write nodejs equivalent for the "Inter-process communication through a pseudo-terminal" (program mypty2) as mentioned here http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html

Comment: Thanks guys for the answer , but I found couple of other projects too https://github.com/ryantenney/node-fork and https://github.com/felixge/node-nix.git . This "node-nix" seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Web Workers API. It is the standard to spawn background processes in server.

For Nodejs, we have the following library >

https://github.com/cramforce/node-worker

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Child Processes](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/child_processes.html) in the [NodeJS docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/index.html). Then check out [Forever](https://github.com/indexzero/forever) as an example of how to use them.